# Finding U2 using superposition for this op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

Using superposition I have found U1 and now I'm finding U2.

[image]

To solve U2 I went with this approach

R_2+R_4=2R       because they are in series
R_3//R_5=  R/2        because they are in series

[image]

[image]

This is the result I came up with, I was hoping for some advice if I tackled this in the right way

Comment: So - Ua2 has the dimension Ohm ?

Comment: @LvW, no voltage , the resistors are 10kOhm. The problem is to find  what is the effect of these signals at the output terminal of the circuit . I found U1 and above is my attempt for U2 but not sure if the calculation is right

Comment: Do you realize that the term U2 does not appear in the given expression? What means "...to solve U2..." ? Do you want to know how U2 influences the opamp output? If yes - you should mention it. And wjat is the purpose of the second figure? It has no output - hence, what do you want to show?

Comment: @LvW, I just added the picture to show how I came up to 5R/3.  yes it is supposed to show how U2 influences the opamp output and that equation above is my result which I can't confirm it is is right

Answer (score 1):

You computed the load on U2 not the attenuation ratio. Also for practical reasons all R’s  should have K after the ohm value.  so try again using the methods of mesh or Norton Transforms or whatever.

1) separate load from source
2) compute equivalent cct of source from left side divider ratio Veq=1/2*U2, Req=  R2//R3
3) compute V(R5) across R5 in next diagram

e.g. [image]

Comment: Stewart, I just wanted  to show how U2 influences the opamp output and that equation above is my result, which I can't confirm it is is right

Comment: That gain is incorrect because you start with equivalent load R on U2 by working backwards. That is not U(R5) but rather Req=U2/I2

Comment: can you please show me, I know I'm asking for too much but I really want to understand and see how it is done. btw could it be that Ua2=2/5

Comment: No it is 1/5 U2 (even if it were buffered in between, you know it has to be less than 1/2*1/2

Comment: what I find confusing is that I followed a tutorial  with the same ciruits just different values as I have shown in the three steps and based on that I have gotten 5R73 or if I put 10kohm it is 50kohm/3.   I followed this https://www.e-education.psu.edu/ebf483/node/558

Comment: Again that only computed the equivalent source load and not the forward attenuation.

Comment: I have made changes to the question

Comment: Still wrong ... look at my dwg and solve for Vin+ then use the correct gain ratio values 1+0.1

Comment: sorry but your drawing is a bit too messy and I can't seem to understand it. Some more information on how you did it  would be great

Comment: ok read until you understand and if not , which part?

Comment: I don't understand your second graph. I'm asuming this U2*R3/(R3+R2) is the voltage divider even though I don't know what does * mean. and then the right part of the graph I'm just lost there. As a final result what is your Ua2 equal to ?

Comment: times = * = x....